# How to safely sanitize / escape text in a wordpress widget input field (html capable)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a question for the PHP / wordpress pros, concerning safe programming techniques. (Edit - the short version:) If I want a user to be able to enter hmtl into a text field in a wordpress widget backend, is it safe enough to just do with using esc_attr in the input field code?

Currently I am using this code for the input fields:

```
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'mycode_content' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Inhalt:' ); ?></label>
    <textarea class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'mycode_content' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'mycode_content' ); ?>" rows="5"><?php echo esc_attr( $mycode_content ); ?></textarea>
</p>
```

Then the values the user enters are applied:

```
public function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
{
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = (!empty($new_instance['title'])) ? strip_tags($new_instance['title']) : '';
    if(current_user_can('unfiltered_html')) {
        $instance['mycode_content'] = $new_instance['mycode_content'];
    } else {
        $instance['mycode_content'] = wp_kses_post($new_instance['mycode_content']);
    }
    $instance['filter'] = 'mycode_content';
    return $instance;
}
```

There is no sanitation done when outputting all this to the frontend:

```
if(!empty($title)) {
    echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
}
if(!empty($mycode_content)) {
    echo $mycode_content;
}
```

So Im using esc_attr when displaying title and content in the backend and strip_tags for the new title after it is input. I basically copied this from the wordpress text widget. But is it safe? For example, there is this line in the input code block:

if ( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) )

If this tests to yes then we just copy the input from the user into the database without further sanitzing. This makes me kind of nervous, I would hate it to do something wrong here.

Comment: Questions asking to *review* code *could* go to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The whole code is a little longer than that... but I guess I made this too long, anyway. My basic question is: If I want a user to be able to enter hmtl into the text field, is it safe enough to just do it this way, with only esc_attr used in the input field code?

Comment: @JQest add a question to your post, please don't post essentials parts of your post to just the comments as the comments are kind of unpredictable and can be removed at any time for any reason.